# How to replace int value to enum value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What event of `DataGridView` should i use to replace integer value to appropriate value of some `enum`?

I'm using Linq-To-Sql and stored proc to fill grid with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)